# How to create registry for bitbucket source in jspm?

Tags: package, bitbucket, package-managers, jspm

I am not familiar in jspm and its registry. I have a private source in bitbucket and I need to create a registry for this in jspm. I am using nodejs with gulp task runner in my source. I researched the jspm doc and there is no information for bitbucket.

I have used the below config in my package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
   .....
   "jspm": "^0.16.39",
   "jspm-git": "^0.4.5"
 }    
 "jspm": {
    "registry": "jspm",
    "name": "my-package",
    "registries": {      
      "bitbucket": {
        "baseurl": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/",
        "handler": "jspm-git"
      }
    }
  }
```

Is it enough for creating a registry in jspm?

How to use bitbucket repository in jspm registry and how to install it?

Is there any doc or steps available in online?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command:

```
jspm registry create bitbucket jspm-git
```

When it asks for the url set the base one:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org
```

No need to set the advanced configurations. It will use the system ssh public key to authenticate with bitbucket.

To add your repository into the package.json simply add:

```
"new-component": "bitbucket:gguridi/repository@master",
```

Executing jspm install should retrieve the code.